# How do I convert SQL statement with alias in a valid Laravel query builder?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, query-builder

I am working on a Laravel 8 application. I have the flowing SQL statement containing the alias `country` for the column `name` of the `countries` table:

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name, countries.name as country FROM users LEFT JOIN countries ON countries.id = users.country_id
```

I have used **[this online tool](https://sql2builder.github.io/)** to convert it to a  valid  Laravel query builder.

##### The problem

Unfortunately, the result (visible below), ignores the alias and displays the colum as *name* instead of *country*:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoin('countries','users.country_id','=','countries.id')
    ->select('users.first_name','users.last_name','countries.name')
    ->get();
```

###### How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that

```
DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoin('countries','users.country_id','=','countries.id')
    ->select('users.first_name','users.last_name','countries.name as country')
    ->get();
```